# Solr DataImportHandler - indexing multiple, related XML documents

Tags: solr

Let's say I have two XML document types, A and B, that look like this:

**A:**

```xml
<xml>
    <a>
        <name>First Number</name>
        <num>1</num>
    </a>
    <a>
        <name>Second Number</name>
        <num>2</num>
    </a>
</xml>
```

**B:**

```xml
<xml>
    <b>
        <aKey>1</aKey>
        <value>one</value>
    </b>
    <b>
        <aKey>2</aKey>
        <value>two</value>
    </b>
</xml>
```

I'd like to index it like this:

```xml
<doc>
    <str name="name">First Name</str>
    <int name="num">1</int>
    <str name="spoken">one</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="name">Second Name</str>
    <int name="num">2</int>
    <str name="spoken">two</str>
</doc>
```

So, in effect, I'm trying to use a value from A as a key in B. Using DataImportHandler, I've used the following as my data config definition:

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
        <entity name="document" transformer="LogTransformer" logLevel="trace"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" baseDir="/tmp/somedir"
            fileName="A.*.xml$" recursive="false" rootEntity="false"
            dataSource="null">
            <entity name="a"
                transformer="RegexTransformer,TemplateTransformer,LogTransformer"
                logLevel="trace" processor="XPathEntityProcessor" url="${document.fileAbsolutePath}"
                stream="true" rootEntity="true" forEach="/xml/a">
                <field column="name" xpath="/xml/a/name" />
                <field column="num" xpath="/xml/a/num" />


                <entity name="b" transformer="LogTransformer"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor" url="/tmp/somedir/b.xml"
                    stream="false" forEach="/xml/b" logLevel="trace">
                    <field column="spoken" xpath="/xml/b/value[../aKey=${a.num}]" />
                </entity>

            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

However, I encounter two problems:

1. I can't get the XPath expression with the predicate to match any rows; regardless of whether I use an alternative like `/xml/b[aKey=${a.num}]/value`, or even hardcoded value for `aKey`.
2. Even when I remove the predicate, the parser goes through the B file once for every row in A, which is obviously inefficient.

My question is: **how, in light of the problems listed above, do I index the data correctly and efficiently with the DataImportHandler**?

I'm using Solr 3.6.2 .

*Note: This is a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666061/i-want-to-use-multiple-datasources-in-dataimporthandler-in-solr-and-pass-url-val), but it deals with two XML document types instead of a RDBMS and an XML document.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with another solution due to an additional design requirement I didn't originally mention. What follows is the explanation and discussion. So....

### If you only have one or a couple of import flow types for your Solr instances:

Then it might be best to go with [Achim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658391/724361) and develop your own importer - either, as Achim suggests, in your favorite scripting language, or, in Java, using *SolrJ's*
 `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer`.

This is because the DataImportHandler framework does have a sudden spike in its learning curve once you need to define more complex import flows.

### If you have a nontrivial number of different import flows:

Then I would suggest you consider staying with the DataImportHandler since **you will probably end up implementing something similar anyway**. And, as the framework is quite modular and extendable, customization isn't a problem.

This is the additional requirement I mentioned, so in the end I went with that route.

How I solved my particular quandary was indexing the files I needed to reference into separate cores and using a modified `SolrEntityProcessor` to access that data. The modifications were as follows:

- applying the patch for the [sub-entity problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734308/solrentityprocessor-is-called-only-once-for-sub-entities),
- adding caching (quick solution using Guava, there's probably a better way using an available Solr API for accessing other cores locally, but I was in a bit of a hurry at that point).

If you don't want to create a new core for each file, an alternative would be an extension of Achim's idea, i.e. creating a custom `EntityProcessor` that would preload the data and enable querying it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I have very bad experiences using DataImportHandler for that kind of data. A simple python script to merge your data would probably be smaller than your current configuration and much more readable. Depending on your requirements and data size, you could create a temporary xml file or you could directly pipe results to SOLR. If you really have to use the DataImportHandler, you could use a URLDataSource and setup a minimal server which generates your xml. Obvioulsy I'm a Python fan, but it's quite likely that it's also an easy job in Ruby, Perl, ...

Comment: I've got absolutely no problem with Python :). However, my concern is that DIH has some optimizations which I'd dislike to lose - I may be wrong on this, but it seems to load the data "directly" (since it's a handler) rather than going over HTTP. So, in the interest of completeness, could you elaborate on how you solved the problem of optimizing your scripts so that performance is comparable to DIH, vs a naive solution that uploads one row at a time - and is certainly much slower in our case (large, millions-of-records dataset) than DIH?

Comment: I have no exact figures to share, but I think there is a missunderstanding: The "naive" solution does not upload one row at a time! Have a look at the post.sh sample script in SOLR distribution. It is using curl to post a single xml file to the update handler of SOLR. If you post from/to localhost, there should be only a minimal ignorable overhead. I would take every bet that reading from disc and merging your data takes much more time.

Comment: That's certainly true, but as I said, I literally have millions of entities, and I'm afraid that sending it all in one request would be prohibitive, if only for the memory requirements involved (it would be also arguably worse than sending it one record at a time for streaming reads). I was asking about buffering strategies that work well with Solr in this case, when compared to the DIH.

Comment: Sorry, I can only contribute my experiences: SOLR does not seem to load posted files completly into memory. I posted only several 100k records (but several GB of XML data) to SOLR which worked fine on a small machine, having less memory than the size of my index. And if you really want to use DIH, you can still use a URLDataSource and implement a minimal server using Flask, Twisted, Tornado, ...

Comment: Actually, that's similar enough in terms of data topology. What I meant in terms of memory is that at least your parser has to store all the records if it would send them in one request - but I'm assuming this is not the case (i.e. you're splitting your data into several requests)?

Comment: Don't know if we are talking about the same problem. If your xml files are organized in a way that forces you to load them into memory, that's a problem of your data, but not of DIH. Yould would have that problem in any case. Otherwise you could parse your files in a "SAX-like" way, generate SOLR records on the fly and stream them to your SOLR server. So you have only one request, which incrementially sends records to SOLR, not holding everything in memory, but executing only a single HTTP request.

Comment: Alright, I think I get what you mean. Thanks - I'll hold out a bit for any other answers, but otherwise, the bounty'll go to you of course.